# Detect int32 overflow using 0xFFFFFFFF masking in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, overflow, sign

I find using 0xFFFFFFFF masking to detect int32 overflow in Python may work for positive numbers.

The expression:

```
x & 0xFFFFFFFF == x
```

will return `True` if x doesn't oveflow and x is larger than 0.

However, this expression doesn't work for negative integers, for example:

```
(-7 & 0xFFFFFFFF) == -7
```

will return `False`, though `-7` shouldn't overflow the int32 ranges..

Does anyone have ideas about why this approach doesn't work for `-7` and how to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because Python doesn't consider any fixed width for numbers. So you don't have any sign bit like that we have for *C/C++* languages (The most significant bit). In the other words, when you do a *bit-wise AND* between the negative number and `0xffff`, the result is a big positive number instead of the negative number:

```
>>> print(-7 & 0xFFFF)
65529
>>> print(-7 & 0xFFFFFFFF)
4294967289
>>>
```

A confirmation for above claim:

```
>>> x = -1
>>> y = -2
>>> z = -4
>>> x.bit_length()
1
>>> y.bit_length()
2
>>> z.bit_length()
3
>>>
```

While in *C/C++* languages as we have a **fixed width** for numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int i = -7 & 0xFFFFFFFF;
  std::cout <<  i;
}
```

the output is the same negative number (If we choose correct length for right side of `&` operator):

```
-7
```

---

I guess you need to define a function to aim your goal and passing the number with the length.(4 byte or 8 byte for example).

Something like this:

```
>>> def isOverflow(num, width=32):
    if num > 0 and num > 2**(width-1) -1 :
        return True
    elif num < 0 and abs(num) > 2**(width-1):
        return True
    return False
```

Or the more efficient version:

```
def isOverflow(num, width=32):
    if num > 0:
        if num >> width-1:
            return True
    elif num < 0:
        if abs(num) > (1 << width - 1):
            return True
    return False
```

That works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> isOverflow(-129,8)
True
>>> isOverflow(-128,8)
False
>>> isOverflow(128,8)
True
>>> isOverflow(127,8)
False
>>> isOverflow(0x7fffffff)
False
>>> isOverflow(0x8fffffff)
True
```